# Can I avoid for loop for operations within a vector?

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

Is there a way to calculate the 4th column in the data table (timeout) without a for loop? Every i th row of that column uses the i-1 th row, so it takes a lot of time to generate as I increase the number of rows.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
id = 1:200, 
timein = cumsum(runif(200,1,6)),
servtime = runif(200,3,4))

dt[,"timeout"] <- dt$timein # initialisation of timeout column

# update column timeout
for(i in 2:200) {
dt$timeout[i] <- max(dt$timein[i], dt$timeout[i-1]) +  dt$servtime[i]
}
```

Comment: your actual problem aside, you really should read the `data.table` FAQ, as you've made a bunch of large mistakes in regards to how one should use a `data.table` (e.g. your first timeout column creation should be instead `dt[, timeout := timein]`)

Comment: Thanks. I am a newbie in R. Haven't coded for over 15 years. I used to code in Fortran for scientific applications.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see an easy way in base R to use vectorized operators to speed this up, but you could use Rcpp to speed up the operation:

```
library(Rcpp)
get.timeout <- cppFunction("
NumericVector getTimeout(NumericVector timein, NumericVector servtime) {
  const int n = timein.size();
  NumericVector timeout(n);
  timeout[0] = timein[0];
  for (int i=1; i < n; ++i) {
    timeout[i] = fmax(timein[i], timeout[i-1]) + servtime[i];
  }
  return timeout;
}")
```

This is quicker than the solution with a for loop:

```
for.loop <- function(timein, servtime) {
  timeout <- dt$timein
  n <- length(timeout)
  for(i in 2:n) {
    timeout[i] <- max(timein[i], timeout[i-1]) +  servtime[i]
  }
  return(timeout)
}
all.equal(for.loop(dt$timein, dt$servtime), get.timeout(dt$timein, dt$servtime))
# [1] TRUE
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(for.loop(dt$timein, dt$servtime), get.timeout(dt$timein, dt$servtime))
# Unit: microseconds
#                                 expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#     for.loop(dt$timein, dt$servtime) 414.040 429.5315 438.68765 435.4000 445.1185 506.162   100
#  get.timeout(dt$timein, dt$servtime)  22.432  23.9305  28.54934  27.9135  28.6670  97.259   100
```

The advantage will likely increase for larger inputs.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the Rcpp code and it ran 20,000 rows instantly!